# openmp fortran program crash

Tags: openmp

i try to modify a simple *reading* code from serial to openmp.

I can't able to understand what kind of error message i have, if there is a problem with the code, whit the intel fotran compiler or something else.

```
program lettura
implicit none

INTEGER*8::n,i,j,m,s,t,q
CHARACTER*70:: filename,k
REAL*8::sum,dummy
REAL*8,ALLOCATABLE::dati(:,:),dats(:,:)
CHARACTER*120::nomefile


open(10,file='bin.txt')
n=0
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(q)


do
read(10,*,end=100)
n=n+1
end do
100 continue
rewind(10)

allocate(dati(11,n))

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do i=1,n
read(10,*) dati(1,i),dati(2,i),dati(3,i),dati(4,i),dati(5,i),dati(6,i),dati(7,i) &
&,dati(8,i),dati(9,i),dati(10,i),dati(11,i)
end do
!$OMP END DO




j=1

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do i=1, n-1
     if (dati(3,i+1) > dati(3,i)) then
            write(k,*) j
        k=adjustl(k)
        filename='where'//trim(k)//'.txt'
        open(2,file=filename)
        close(2)
            j=j+1
         end if
end do
!$OMP END DO




j=1
open(2,file='where1.txt')

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do i=1, n-1
     if (dati(3,i+1) == dati(3,i)) then
        write(2,*) dati(1,i),dati(2,i),dati(3,i),dati(4,i),dati(5,i),dati(6,i),dati(7,i) &
                &,dati(8,i),dati(9,i),dati(10,i),dati(11,i)
            else
        write(2,*) dati(1,i),dati(2,i),dati(3,i),dati(4,i),dati(5,i),dati(6,i),dati(7,i) &
                &,dati(8,i),dati(9,i),dati(10,i),dati(11,i)
        close(2)
        j=j+1
        write(k,*) j
        k=adjustl(k)
        filename='where'//trim(k)//'.txt'
        open(2,file=filename)
print *,j,"/ 54"
     end if
end do
!$OMP END DO
open(3,file='Sigma.txt')


!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do i=1, j-1
    write(k,*) i
    k=adjustl(k)
    nomefile='where'//trim(k)//'.txt'
    open(4,file=nomefile)

!print *,i contatore del numero di file
!calcolare righe del file
m=0
    do 
      read(4,*,end=101)
      m=m+1
    end do
      101 continue
      rewind(4)
! fine righe file
! scrive la matrice del file dats(11,m), m: # di righe
    allocate(dats(11,m))

! fa il calcolo sulla matrice
        sum=0
    do s=1, m-1
      read(4,*) dummy,dummy,dummy,dats(4,s),dats(5,s)
      sum=sum+(1/(dats(4,s))*((2/(dats(5,s)-1))-1)**2)
        end do
! scrive sul file 3
print *, sum
    WRITE(3,*) (sum/(m-1))
    close(4)
    deallocate(dats)

end do
!$OMP END DO
 close(3)
!$OMP END PARALLEL
end program lettura
```

When i try to compile it:

```
ifort -openmp -w dati_omp.f90
export OMP_NUM_THREDS=2
./a.out
```

I receive this message:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              000000000045AA90  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000453BBC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000041E7E8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004037C3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libiomp5.so        00007F413793F4F3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Someone can help me please???

Answer (score 0):

From the OpenMP standard, section 2.4:

> Unsynchronized use of Fortran I/O statements by multiple threads on
>   the same unit has unspecified behavior.

Looking at your code, it seems that statements like:

```
!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do i=1,n
read(10,*) dati(1,i),dati(2,i),dati(3,i),dati(4,i),dati(5,i),dati(6,i),dati(7,i) &
&,dati(8,i),dati(9,i),dati(10,i),dati(11,i)
end do
!$OMP END DO
```

are part of this case and trigger an unspecified behavior. I would suggest to modify your code and synchronize the access from multiple threads to the same unit.